# Android Signed Apk genarate issue

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, retrofit

While I am trying to get Signed Apk from the android studio, I got the below error

**Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven/junit/junit/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project**

How to rectify this issue.

Comment: Do exactly what it is saying `Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`

Comment: if I disable Gradle offline mode, retrofit not working @JunaidKhalid

Comment: What do you mean? what is exception in online mode?

Comment: in online mode i am not able to generate signed apk, suppose If i remove       //  maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven" } ,I can able to generate apk but retrofit not working @JunaidKhalid

Comment: why are you removing maven

Comment: error in that particular line only so just tried to find purpose,i have removed, any solution pls @JunaidKhalid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243267/discussion-between-junaid-khalid-and-murugananthams).

Comment: @MurugananthamS - from error its look like unable to download the repository because of no internet or repository even no more present in bintray, if you post the build.gradle file code as well, easy to understand what version you using.